# is there a way to show changes in several repos in team explorer in MSVS?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I need to browse repo changes for several repos in MSVS Team Explorer. Repos are plain git, there's no TFS integration

Team Explorer looks like this (2nd repo is selected and it's where .sln resides):

[image: team explorer, showing 2 repos]

By default, Team Explorer shows only the repo in which the .sln file resides, while actually codebase uses 2 repos (2ns is Shared). And I can't browse the 2nd repo's code changes other then by opening it in an empty solution this way:

[image: team explorer, way to open 2nd repo]

And it's clearly not an option since it closes the solution with codebase, which I want to navigate from Team Explorer.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to make Team Explorer work the way I need?
2. If not, would you kindly recommend in **comments, not answers** (otherwise post's gonna be closed I think) an alternative widget with git changes nicely integrated into MSVS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a plugin called **"Easy Git Integration Tools"**, it has "pending changes" window. But it's breaking the current branch VS control at the right bottom pane in MSVS.

I discovered that if I switch MSVS to builtin git source control provider instead of TFS, it starts to work as supposed to: **"Team Explorer - Changes" (w/ Git source control provider)** window shows changed files from all projects and disc directories.

There is also **"Git Tools"** plugin, but Team Explorer with git plus **"Git Diff Margin"** are enough for my case.